# What is the Z-Transform $u_n =\cos(n+1)\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, z-transform

I have tried using the putting it into $\cos(n\theta)$ = $\frac{z (z-cos\theta)}{z^2 - 2zcos\theta+1}$ formula, but my answer is wrong.

$u_n = \cos(n+1)\theta.$

Comment: I have edited my approach as asked and am not able to move past it and yeah I just tried LaTex by using inspect show tex commands from some other question about z-transform

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, @newbz!